# Creating a hyperlink in NSIS Custom Page: doesn't do anything

Tags: installation, nsis

I am trying to place a hyperlink in one of my NSIS pages.

**My Problem:** The hyperlink doesn't open the webpage or even web browser when clicked(nothing happens) and when I hover over the link it doesn't underline.

Am I using the hyperlink incorrectly? Is a hyperlink in a NSIS page meant to underline/highlight when hovered over?

Can you help me get my code to create a functioning hyperlink?

```
${NSD_CreateLink} 218u 128u 60u 20u "Manual Installation"
Pop $R9
${NSD_OnClick} $R9 onManualInstallClick

Function onManualInstallClick
    ExecShell "open" "http://www.google.com.au" 
FunctionEnd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to pop the HWND parameter that is pushed into stack while calling the onClick callback.

Try

```
!define DEBUG `System::Call kernel32::OutputDebugString(ts)`
Function onManualInstallClick
    pop $0
    ${DEBUG} "Link clicked"
    ExecShell "open" "http://www.google.com.au" 
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. But it still doesn't open the web browser, nothing happens. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @JakeM: Is the callback executed ? I have modified my example to add some trace with the debug api. You can catch if with the free [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) Sysinternal tool now available in MS site.

Comment: thanks for the help. Turns out my hyperlink window was behind another transparent window. Which meant it wasn't receiving mouse events